# Time is showing according to date in jquery. How to Solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have written jquery datetimepicker to show only Time from DateTime:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <span>Start Time:@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @class = "form-control", id="StartTime", @placeholder = "hh:mm A" })</span>
</div>
```

and my jquery function to show the time is

```
$(function(){

   $("#StartTime").datetimepicker({
                format: "hh:mm A"
            }).data("DateTimePicker").date(moment.unix(getUrlParameter("time")).utc());
});
```

It is formatted in correct order but the problem is time always shows according to the month of the date. Suppose if time date is 8/14/2020 the time shows 8 A.M similarly if date is 10/14/2020 the time shows 10 P.M. . It discards the time value of date time. How to solve this issue?